# how to call a selected select value with ajax and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a product update modal which is contains `MainCategory`, `Category`, `SubCategory` , `ChildCategory` . So I have script which calls other `Category`, `SubCategory` , `ChildCategory` with ajax when the new  `MainCategory` selected.

But it's an update modal so when i just open the modal, there are only curreny values in those selects. But there are not other `Category`, `SubCategory` , `ChildCategory` values in those selects. I need those values so user can select another one.

I allready think about to call those `Category`, `SubCategory` , `ChildCategory` on the back-end and send it to front-end with view model but i dont wanna send lots of query to my database. Am i able to do that or not ? if i am able to do then how ?
[image]

HTML

```
<div class="col">
    <label asp-for="@productUpdate.MainCategoryID" class="control-label">Ana Kategorisi</label>
    <select asp-for="@productUpdate.MainCategoryID" class="form-control" data-width="100%" id="drpMainCatc" name="MainCategoryID" required>
        @if (productUpdate.MainCategoryID != null)
        {
            <option value="@productUpdate.MainCategoryID" selected disabled hidden>@productUpdate.MainCategory.MainCategoryName</option>
            @foreach (var mainCategory in Model.MainCategoriesForDropdownList)
            {
                <option value="@mainCategory.MainCategoryID">@mainCategory.MainCategoryName</option>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
            @foreach (var mainCategory in Model.MainCategoriesForDropdownList)
            {
                <option value="@mainCategory.MainCategoryID">@mainCategory.MainCategoryName</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@productUpdate.MainCategoryID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <label asp-for="@productUpdate.CategoryID" class="control-label">Kategorisi</label>
    <select asp-for="@productUpdate.CategoryID" class="form-control" data-width="100%" id="drpCatc" name="CategoryID" required>
        @if (productUpdate.CategoryID != null)
        {
            <option selected="selected" value="@productUpdate.CategoryID">@productUpdate.Category.CategoryName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@productUpdate.CategoryID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <label asp-for="@productUpdate.SubCategoryID" class="control-label">Alt Kategorisi</label>
    <select asp-for="@productUpdate.SubCategoryID" class="form-control" data-width="100%" id="drpSubCatc" name="SubCategoryID" required>
        @if (productUpdate.SubCategoryID != null)
        {
            <option selected="selected" value="@productUpdate.SubCategoryID">@productUpdate.SubCategory.SubCategoryName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@productUpdate.SubCategoryID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <label asp-for="@productUpdate.ChildCategoryID" class="control-label">2.Alt Kategorisi</label>
    <select asp-for="@productUpdate.ChildCategoryID" class="form-control" data-width="100%" id="drpChildCatc" name="ChildCategoryID" required>
        @if (productUpdate.ChildCategoryID != null)
        {
            <option selected="selected" value="@productUpdate.ChildCategoryID">@productUpdate.ChildCategory.ChildCategoryName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@productUpdate.ChildCategoryID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And Javascript with Ajax Call :

```
<script>
    $("#drpMainCatc").change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var catItems = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Company/GetCategories/?id=' + self.val(),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                catItems += "<option  value='" + "0" + "' disabled selected >" + "Seçiniz" + "</option>";
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    catItems += "<option value='" + item.categoryID + "'>" + item.categoryName + "</option>";
                });
                $("#drpCatc").html(catItems);
                $("#drpCatc").val($('#categoryID').val());
                console.log($("#drpCatc").val($('#categoryID').val()));
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                showError('Kategoriler yüklenirken hata oluştu, tekrar deneyiniz.')
            }
        });
        $("#drpSubCatc").empty();
        $("#drpChildCatc").empty();
    });

    $("#drpCatc").change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var subCatItems = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Company/GetSubCategories/?id=' + self.val(),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                subCatItems += "<option  value='" + "0" + "' disabled selected >" + "Seçiniz" + "</option>";
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    subCatItems += "<option value='" + item.subCategoryID + "'>" + item.subCategoryName + "</option>";
                });
                $("#drpSubCatc").html(subCatItems);
                $("#drpSubCatc").val($('#subCategoryID').val());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                showError('1. Alt Kategoriler yüklenirken hata oluştu, tekrar deneyiniz.')
            },
        }); $("#drpChildCatc").empty();
    });

    $("#drpSubCatc").change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var childCatItems = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Company/GetChildCategories/?id=' + self.val(),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                childCatItems += "<option  value='" + "0" + "' disabled selected >" + "Seçiniz" + "</option>";
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    childCatItems += "<option value='" + item.childCategoryID + "'>" + item.childCategoryName + "</option>";

                });
                $("#drpChildCatc").html(childCatItems);
                $("#drpChildCatc").val($('#childCategoryID').val());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                showError('2. Alt Kategoriler yüklenirken hata oluştu, tekrar deneyiniz.')
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need a `for` loop for child categories too, similar to what you have already done for the main category.

Comment: Hi @BerkGarip, From your gif picture, it seems only the first selectlist could populate correctly when you open the modal, so what you need is to make all the selectlist populated, right? But from your description, you said you dont want send lots of query to database, not sure what does it mean and what is the aim. Could you please share more details?

Comment: @Rena of course. When the modal opens, the select box has the current value as we see. When i didnt trigger the ajax javascript, its just having a one value which is current value. i wanna display other data's too. so i dont wanna send another query to my db while ajax waiting for there. there is a 3 selectbox like that. if i fill others data on the controller, that means im gonna send 3 query and if ajax javascript trigger its gonna send another 3 query too. i wanna avoid those query because its the same which im calling in the ajax. i hope i explained myself well. thank you for your interest